# KOA - dependency for mysql error

Tags: mysql, npm, koa

I am a newbie to KOA framework, facing a issue while installing the mysql dependency using this command **npm install knex-mysql-middleware** on my windows xp machine. Below is the message i am getting on my console.

```
npm WARN package.json path@0.11.14 path is also the name of a node core module.
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, chmod 'E:\testkoa\app3\node_modules\knex-mysql-middleware\node_modules\mysql\node_modules\readable-stream\node_modules\inherits\inherits.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 5.1.2600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "knex-mysql-middleware"
npm ERR! cwd E:\testkoa\app3
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path E:\testkoa\app3\node_modules\knex-mysql-middleware\node_modules\mysql\node_modules\readable-stream\node_modules\inherits\inherits.js
npm ERR! fstream_path E:\testkoa\app3\node_modules\knex-mysql-middleware\node_modules\mysql\node_modules\readable-stream\node_modules\inherits\inherits.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! fstream_finish_call chmod
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:305:19
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'E:\testkoa\app3\node_modules\knex-mysql-middleware\node_modules\mysql\node_modules\readable-stream\node_modules\core-util-is\float.patch'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a very similar problem before.  You might try running:

```
npm cache clean
```

and see if that makes any difference.